# simply dump write xml to screen

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

XML/ASP.net VB newbie here having fun can't find needle in haystack.

I just want to dump some XML to the screen!  Loads of sites tell me how to iterate the nodes, xpath my way in directly.  I just want the whole lot to screen.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load("remote.xml")

Dim writer as XmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter("debug.xml",nothing)
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
doc.Save(writer)
```

Does a sterling job of getting it to a file, but I want it on the screen.  doc.print(writer).....

Please help.

Comment: You can use XDocument to load the xml and ToString() to get the string representation and dump that to the screen.

Comment: To clarify: you are not asking how to read or parse an XML file, you are asking how to display a large block of arbitrary text on a web page. Is that right?

Comment: yes. i don't want to parse it. i just want to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with the innerXml of your doc. Make sure to HtmlEncode it for it to show up. Stick a literalcontrol on your aspx with id='ltXml' and then something like this:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/remote.xml"))

ltXml.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(doc.InnerXml)
```

Edited per comment by OP.

Have the function in your class return the Xml string.

```
Private Class [MyClass]
        Public Shared Function getXml() As String
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("somefile.xml")

        Return HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(doc.InnerXml)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then in your aspx code behind of your webpage call the class function:

```
ltXml.Text = [MyClass].getXml()
```

Comment: this looks good.  however my code is in a class and i'm getting scope errors.  Name 'ltXml' is not declared.  how do let the class see the web page?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the modern [`XDocument` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead of the old, deprecated `XmlDocument`.

[XDocument.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) already returns a nicely formatted version of the XML, so all you need to do is:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("remote.xml")
Dim formatted As String = doc.ToString()
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  What IMPORT declarations do I need? 

`<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>`
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>`
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Linq" %>`
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.XLinq" %>`

I'm getting Type 'XDocument' is not defined.

Comment: @bendecko: `System.Xml.Linq` is fine, be sure to add a reference to `System.Xml.Linq.dll` to your project!

Comment: @bendecko: As a general advise: Such information can be found on [the MSDN page of the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx): The line **Namespace:** defines the import declarations, the line **Assembly:** tells you which reference you need.